# COUNT() function is not working for ID's in oracle ? Checked all themes in the sites ,no one works for me

Tags: sql, oracle, function, count

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT Count(q.test_disciplina_id)"|BROI|",
              p.predmet                  "|Predmet|",
              t.naimenovanie_test        "|TEST|",
              data
       FROM   qvqvaniq_na_test q
              inner join test_disciplina td
                      ON ( q.test_disciplina_id = td.id_disciplina_test )
              inner join test t
                      ON ( td.test_id_test = t.id_test )
              inner join disciplina d
                      ON ( td.disciplina_id_disciplina = d.id_disciplina )
              inner join predmeti p
                      ON ( d.predmeti_id_predmet = p.id_predmet )
       GROUP  BY predmet,
                 naimenovanie_test,
                 data)
WHERE  To_date(data) BETWEEN To_date('2018-01-01') AND To_date('2019-10-10');
```

Comment: What result do you want?  Your question is very confusing.  You say you have "a table", then you have a query that references several tables.  Your result set has columns that are not in your sample data.

Comment: With no example data, expected results, and examples of how the expected results diverge from the actual results it's impossible for anyone to determine what it is you're trying to accomplish. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the tags, include sample data for each table, the results you're getting, and the results you expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Start over with

```
select count(q.test_disciplina_id) 
from qvqvaniq_na_test q
```

and make sure query returns something. Then add another table; test, and so forth. If you don't get expected result in any of those steps, don't go any further until you fix the error.

Query you wrote *looks OK*. With almost no information, it is difficult to guess what might be wrong; here are a few possibilities:

- you should have used outer join
- why did you use an inline view? I don't see any reason. Remove it, and put `WHERE` clause where it belongs
- `WHERE` clause should be rewritten. Currently, it is

  ```
  WHERE To_date(data) BETWEEN To_date('2018-01-01') AND To_date('2019-10-10');
  ```

  - what is `DATA`'s datatype? If it is a string `TO_DATE` should have appropriate format mask, e.g. `to_date(data, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`. If it is a date, then remove `TO_DATE` entirely
  - `to_date('2018-01-01')` also misses format mask. Don't rely on Oracle's implicit conversion, it'll fail sooner or later. Either apply format mask (as previously), e.g. `to_date('2018-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` or use a date literal, `date '2018-01-01'`

  Fixed, it might look like

  ```
  where to_date(data, 'yyyy-mm-dd') between date '2018-01-01' and date '2019-10-10'
  ```

Now, your turn.

Comment: it's worked, thank you, changing my count function and writing data-format solved my  problem